# How to make a typedef or using for a method pointer to a class template?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

I have a object subclassed from `Parent` that creates a child.  It gives the child an `std::function` to call to report status, but in practice the `std:function` would probably always be a method on the parent, so as a convenience an additional constructor is provided that takes that as an argument.

I've made a `typedef` of the `std::function`, but I can't figure out how to make a `typedef` of the method pointer.

```
class Child { // No Hungarian: abstract class, so no variables of this type exist.
  
public:

  typedef std::function< void( Child* child_in, Msg* pmsg ) > FuncCB;

  // can't figure out some way to define an MethodCB.
  //template<T> typedef void (T::*MethodCB)( Child* child_in, Msg* pmsg );

  Child( Parent* pparent_in, FuncCB asynccb_in ) :
      pparent( pparent_in ),
      asynccb_( asynccb_in )
  {
  };

  template<typename T>
  // can't figure out some way to define an MethodCB.
  //Child( Parent* pparent_in, MethodCB pmethod_in ) :
  Child( Parent* pparent_in, void (T::*pmethod_in)() ) :
      Child( pparent_in, [=]( Child* pchild, Msg* pmsg )
                         { (pparent_in->*pmethod_in)( pchild, pmsg ); } )
  {
  };

  // Either way, the callback is stored here:
  FuncCB funccb;


     :
     :
  // When child wants to send a message to parent.  Generally the parent
  // will have a method to take this call, but it could technically be
  // any other std::function object type as well.

  funccb( this, Msg( "blah" ) );
```

Comment: Shouldn't `class Child` be `class BusinessObject` in this sample code?

Comment: What is the point of making it a template if the relevant object is always a `Parent`?

Comment: @francisduvivier sorry, was editing real code to make a clearer example; fixed

Comment: @molbdnilo the creator may be a **subclass** of parent.  I'll edit to clarify that.

Comment: If the member function is not a member of `Parent`, you won't be able to call it through a member pointer. You need to template the parent type as well. (And you need to add the arguments you ignore to the lambda.)

Answer (score 0):

You lambda is not taking any arguments, but to match the signature of `FuncCB` it must take 2 arguments. Fix your lambda and you're good to go:

```
template <typename T>
using MemFunc = void (T::*) ();

using Func = std::function<void(Parent&, int msg)>;

template <typename T>
Child(T& parent, Func f)
{
    f(parent, 10);
}

template <typename T>
Child(T& parent, MemFunc<T> f) :
    Child(parent, [f](Parent& p, int msg) { (p.*f)(); }) // note that the lambda takes 2 arguments here, and we don't use parent, but p to call the member function!
{        
}
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/dWM4j8)

As molbdnilo pointed out tho, this won't work if `T` is anything other than `Parent`. To make this work, you have to cast the parent object to whatever derived type you're passing in. But this requires that you only pass arguments of type `T`, otherwise this will fail:

```
template <typename T>
Child(T& parent, MemFunc<T> f) :
    Child(parent, [f](Parent& p, int msg) { (dynamic_cast<T&>(p).*f)(); })
{        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the missing method pointer args--g++ 6.3.1 didn't actually catch that!  But basically the first half of your answer only works if the caller is passing in a method of the base class Parent, right?  That's definitely not the plan, I'll have *subclasses* of Parent passing in their own methods that Parent doesn't know about.

Comment: That's why I added the second part. You have to make sure to only ever pass objects of type `T` or a subclass thereof into the function. See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/b3PGef).

Comment: Actually, you could use a `static_cast` instead of `dynamic_cast` as well.

Comment: T will never actually be Parent, always a subclass...

Comment: Which is totally fine.

Comment: It will take some time to fully understand Timo and thanks for the detailed responses.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Yz7Tqq) example for clarification on what can go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Why overconstrain the arguments?

```
template <class T, class Fn>
Child (T* parent, Fn fun) : Child(parent, 
                                  [=](Child* child, Msg* msg) {
                                    std::invoke(fun, parent, child, msg);
                                  }) 
{}
```

You can get rid of the ugly lambda syntax too.

```
template <class T, class Fn>
Child (T* parent, Fn fun) : Child(parent, std::bind(fun, parent, _1, _2)) 
{}
```

Yes, `std::bind` is easy and fun.

Comment: I can pass in a method name as Fn?  How is fun less constrained here?  It still has to be a pointer to a method on parent that takes params Child* and Msg*, right?  If this does what I need it's certainly a LOT more elegant...

Comment: Does the bind version allow the compiler to check the arguments to the call?  I'm guessing the bind itself accepts any two-arg function, but then by passing it into the other constructor, that specifies what the args must be,an arg mismatch would generate an error there, right?  The bind goes find but then assignment of bind to std::function is a type mismatch?

Comment: If you add the `std::placeholders::` (or `using` for it) and `#include <functional>` the bind version is less clearly superior.

Comment: (1) Yes, Fn is any callable object. Can be a member function, a non-member function, a lambda, or whatever. T is also anything as long as you can pass it to Fn. Other code may constrain T to be a subclass of Parent. (2) Yes, any type errors will be generated at compile time. Error messages may or may not be user-friendly though. You can use `static_assert` to generate friendly error messages. (3) `using std::placeholders` is inobtrusive IMHO. You need `<functional>` for `std::function` anyway.